# Numerical methods for non-linear diffusion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have the following non-linear diffusion equation, for $\ z(x,t)$:

$\ z_t = -C\sin^m(\omega t) \,x^{hm}\left[hm x^{-1}(z_x)^n + n z_{xx} (z_x)^{n-1}\right]$

Any advice for numerical (or analytical) solutions?

Comment: What are $h, m, x$ referring to?

Comment: x is one of the variables for the function z(x,t); h and m are constants